# Can't migrate database( laravel)

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I am facing problem migrating database using `php artisan migrate` command . 
Can anybody help me figure out what I did wrong here?

Please note I am fairly new with `laravel`.

[image]

Comment: Your database connection name is invalid. I can see you're using mysql, so set it to `DB_CONNECTION=mysql` and run `php artisan config:clear`. Try to migrate again after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set proper database connection in the `.env` file then **restart** your server. Then try to **migrate**. Hope it will helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you DB_CONNECTION is a `localhost` put `mysql`

and your  `config/database 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),`

and your .env  `DB_CONNECTION=mysql`

Answer (score 0):

Your installation isn't pulling your username/password from your `.env` file and it's using the defaults. Assuming this is a new install of Laravel and you just edited `.env.example` then you need to rename that file to just `.env`:

You can run:

```
mv .env.example .env
```

Comment: I created a .env file with all of the contents that .env.example has . Do you think that might cause the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

set these in `.env` file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=fresher
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

give a try to these commands to cleanup things

1 - run `composer dumpautoload`

2 - run `php artisan clear-compiled`

after that run the `php artisan migrate` command